# Serverless: Encrypting a topic on AWS

Tags: encryption, amazon-ses, serverless

I'm creating a topic using Serverless on AWS. This all works fine, however I want to encrypt the topic using SSE. How do I get this done. What should be the format of the YAML file.

So far I have

```yaml
MyTopic:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  Properties:
    TopicName: MyTopic
MyTopicPolicy:
  Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
  Properties:
    Topics:
      - Ref: MyTopic
    PolicyDocument:
      Id: MyTopicPolicy
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Sid: AllowSubscribe
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: <ID>
          Action:
            - SNS:Subscribe            
          Resource: !Ref MyTopic
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a simple SNS topic with default KMS, below is the syntax. I also added email subscription in it. You may change the subscription as per your need:

```
  RedshiftNotificationTopicSNS:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      KmsMasterKeyId: alias/aws/sns
      Subscription:
        - Endpoint: !Ref NotificationEmailId
          Protocol: email
```

Answer (score 5):

As above answer suggests, you will need to reference KMS Key in your SNS Topic definition. You can either use default KMS key for SNS (alias `aws/sns`), or create your own

You can look at CloudFormation below on how to create encrypted topic and KMS Key in the same template - using your own KMS Key. Key policy is set to allow administration and consumption by whole AWS account, though you probably wan to lock this down using least privilege principle, depending on security requirements of environment you are working in.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Demo template for Encrypted SNS Topic

Resources:
  SNSKMSKey:
    Type: 'AWS::KMS::Key'
    Properties:
      Description: Demo KMS Key Policy
      Enabled: true
      EnableKeyRotation: true
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: KmsKeyPolicy
        Statement:
          - Sid: SimpleKeyPolicyAllowAccountAdmin
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root"
            Action:
              - 'kms:*'
            Resource: '*'
          - Sid: SimpleKeyPolicyAllowAccountUsage
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root"
            Action:
              - 'kms:Decrypt'
              - 'kms:Encrypt'
              - 'kms:GenerateDataKey*'
              - 'kms:DescribeKey'
            Resource: '*'


  SNSKmeKeyAlias:
    Type: "AWS::KMS::Alias"
    Properties:
      AliasName: !Sub "alias/${AWS::StackName}-SNSEncryptionKey"
      TargetKeyId: !Ref SNSKMSKey

  # -- Encrypted  SNS Topic -- #
  EncryptedSNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-EncryptedSNSTopic"
      KmsMasterKeyId: !Ref SNSKMSKey


Outputs:
  KmsKeyId:
    Value: !Ref SNSKMSKey
  TopicArn:
    Value: !Ref EncryptedSNSTopic
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `KmsMasterKeyId`

```
MyTopic:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  Properties:
    TopicName: MyTopic
    KmsMasterKeyId: 1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab
```

Source: [AWS Cloudformation document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeKey.html#API_DescribeKey_RequestParameters)

Comment: Thanks for this, what does `KmsMasterKeyId` indicate.  Is this something that will get automatically picked up?

Comment: This is similar to specifying an ARN. Mark the answer correct if it helped. Thanks